# svn2git error PROPFIND request failed

Tags: github

I have Ruby, RubyGems, and svn2git installed under 32 bit windows 7.

```
svn2git https://code.google.com/p/skyrim-plugin-decoding-project/ --rootistrunk --revision 1:1693 --authors ~/authors.txt --verbose
```

The above line returns the following error:

```
Running command: git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=https://code.g
oogle.com/p/skyrim-plugin-decoding-project/
Initialized empty Git repository in e:/tes5edit/.git/
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/p/skyrim-plugin-decoding-p
roject': PROPFIND of '/p/skyrim-plugin-decoding-project': 405 Method Not Allowed
 (https://code.google.com) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 310

command failed:
git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=https://code.google.com/p/skyri
m-plugin-decoding-project/
```

I read something about svnadmin so I tried the following

```
svnadmin: E205000: Repository argument required
```

I don't know what the argument would be.

I have never used GitBash or any of these programs.  I have no idea what the proper commands would be to resolve the issue.  I am also new to Git and have very little experience with it.

```
git svn clone http://my-project.googlecode.com/svn/ \
      --authors-file=users.txt --no-metadata -s my_project
```

The standard commands also give errors

```
E:\TES5Edit_Git> git svn init https://code.google.com/p/skyrim-plugin-decoding-p
roject/
Initialized empty Git repository in E:/TES5Edit_Git/.git/
E:\TES5Edit_Git [master]> git config svn.authorsfile ./authors.txt
E:\TES5Edit_Git [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git svn fetch
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/p/skyrim-plugin-decoding-p
roject': PROPFIND of '/p/skyrim-plugin-decoding-project': 405 Method Not Allowed
 (https://code.google.com) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148

E:\TES5Edit_Git [master +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

As long as it makes a repo I can push I don't care how I do it.  However, I did not start with a standard setup in the beginning and no idea what I was doing.  So I want the clone to start at commit 1 and consider root as master, and all commits that make any kind of folder, rename folders, move folders, delete folders, all of everything created as branches.

Answer (score 0):

After asking some friends I realized I had been using the wrong URL.

```
svn2git http://skyrim-plugin-decoding-project.googlecode.com/svn/ --rootistrunk --revision 1:1693 --authors ~/authors.txt --verbose
```

That would have been the correct init statment